# inequality $\frac{2(x + y)^2}{2x^2 + y^2} \leq 3$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

I'm looking for a "nice" way to show that the following inequality holds, i.e. without differentiating and determining the maximum:

$$
\frac{2(x + y)^2}{2x^2+ y^2} \leq 3 \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}
$$

It's rather easy to show

$$
\frac{4xy}{x^2 + y^2} \le 2
$$

and obviously

$$
\frac{2x^2 + 2y^2}{2x^2+y^2} \le 2
$$

but combining these two does not give me a sufficient low bound.

Comment: Cross multiplying and factoring does it. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\frac{2(x + y)²}{2x² + y²} \le 3 \iff 2x^2+4xy+2y^2\le 6x^2+3y^2 \\\iff0 \le 4x^2-4xy+y^2=(2x-y)^2.\blacksquare$$

Answer (score 4):

by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$(2x^2+y^2)(1+2)\ge {(\sqrt{2}x+\sqrt{2}y)}^2=2{(x+y)}^2$$

Comment: why is there a vote to delete this post?

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=l.x$; we have:

$\frac{2[(l+1)x]^2}{x^2(l^2+2)}=\frac {2l^2+4l+2}{l62+2}=2+\frac{4l-2}{l^2+2}$

$\frac{4l-2}{l^2+2}<1$

because:

$(l-2)^2>0$

$l^2-4l+2+2>0$

$4l-2<l^2+2$

If $l=2$ the equality holds.

Answer (score 2):

Well $2x^2+y^2> 0$ and $2(x+y)^2\ge 0$ so

So $\frac{2(x + y)^2}{2x^2+ y^2} \leq 3\iff$

$2(x+y)^2 \leq3(2x^2 + y^2) \iff$

$2x^2 + 4xy +2y^2 \leq 6x^2 + 3y^2 \iff$

$0 \leq 4x^2 -4xy +y^2 \iff$

$0 \leq(2x -y)^2 \iff$ God's in his heaven and all's right in the world.

Answer (score 2):

How about this method?
$$\frac{2(x + y)²}{2x² + y²}-3=\frac{2x^2+4xy+2y^2-(6x^2+3y^2)}{2x^2+y^2}=-\frac{4x^2+4xy+y^2}{2x^2+y^2}=-\frac{(2x-y)^2}{2x^2+y^2}\le0..$$